# Fragment constantly updated

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity

I've got a FragmentActivity when I instantiate three different (n, n+1, n+2) Fragments.
I need to keep each Fragment updated when user swipes to it, so I used *ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener.onPageSelected* in the Fragment Activity, so when user swipes to n+1 or n+2 Fragment and again to n that function update the content.
Without using this workaround if I'm in the Fragment n+1, both n and n+2 are already loaded! I'd like instead that the Fragment load when the user swipes to it, without "pre-load".

This workaround works fine for me but it has a problem: the n Fragment that is the first in the list at start up of the app doesn't load its content. To load its content I have to swipe to n+1 then go back to n.

I know that the content of the Fragment should be setted on the class called at the moment of instantiate the fragment and that extends Fragment class, but in this way I don't know how to keep up to date each Fragment, as I do using *onPageSelected*.

Any suggestions?

**EDIT 1:**
I istantiate my fragments in this way in *onCreate()*:

```
    for(int x = 0; x < 3; x++) {
        Bundle b = new Bundle();
        b.putString( "id" , x );
        Fragment myFrag = Fragment.instantiate( myContext , Mm_FragmentPage.class.getName() );
        myFrag.setArguments( b );
        fragments.add(myFrag);
    }
```

Then I set the adapter in the *ViewPager*:

```
    mPagerAdapter = new PagerAdapter( super.getSupportFragmentManager() , fragments );
    mPager.setAdapter( mPagerAdapter );
```

Then I use the adapter in the *TitlePageIndicator*

```
    titleIndicator = (TitlePageIndicator) findViewById( R.id.titleFragments );
    titleIndicator.setViewPager( mPager );
    titleIndicator.setOnPageChangeListener( new myPageChangeListener() );
```

And, at the end, the class *PagerAdapter*:

```
public class PagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter
{
    // fragments to instantiate in the viewpager
    private List<Fragment> fragments;

    // constructor
    public PagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, List<Fragment> fragments)
    {
        super(fm);
        this.fragments = fragments;
    }

    // return access to fragment from position, required override
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position)
    {
        return this.fragments.get(position);
    }

    // number of fragments in list, required override
    @Override
    public int getCount()
    {
        return this.fragments.size();
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position)
    {
        return getResources().getStringArray( R.array.tab_header_name )[ position ];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, so first thing you need to set **OnPageChangeListener** on the ViewPager and implement method *onPageSelected(int i)* and call the adapter's *notifyDataSetChanged()*, like so:

```
    mPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int i, float v, int i2) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int i) {
            //Tell the adapter that the content was changed
            mPager.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int i) {

        }
    });
```

In order to keep the fragments updated, you need to extends **FragmentStatePagerAdapter** and not **FragmentPagerAdapter** like what you did. The difference is that with **FragmentPagerAdapter** the **ViewPager** will never re-create the fragments, while in **FragmentStatePagerAdapter** it will.

Then on *getItem(..)* make sure to return a new instance of the fragment with the new content by passing the content to its arguments via *setArguments()*. Then override also *getItemPosition(..)* to tell the adapter that the fragment is not found, and therefore it must re-create it.

```
public class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
        //List to hold the fragments to be shown
        //NOTE: It's a list of Fragment classes, not a list of Fragment instances!
        private List<Class<? extends Fragment> fragments;

        public MyPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
            fragments.add(SomeFragment.class); 
            fragments.add(AnotherFragment.class);
            fragments.add(MoreFragment.class);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int i) {
            try {
                //Creates a new instance of the fragment
                Fragment instance = fragments.get(i).newInstance();
                //Put the new content by passing Bundle with new content
                instance.setArguments(args);
                return instance;
                } catch (InstantiationException e) {
                  e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                  e.printStackTrace();
              }
            return null;
          }


        @Override
        public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
            //NOTE: you might want to put better logic here
            return POSITION_NONE;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return pages.size();
        }
    }
```

Every time you slide from one fragment to another, *onPageSelected()* will be fired calling notifyDataSetChanged() which will force the adapter to check also if the position of the fragment has changed. Since we return POSITION_NONE in *getItemPosition(..)*, the adapter thinks that the position changed and will then call *getItem(i)*. In *getItem(i)* we return a new instance (optionally, passing new arguments). Problem solved! :)

I just tested it by myself, created a small app that have a counter which increases everytime the user slides the page and it works!

This way you can drop the *ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener.onPageSelected*.
[Learn more](http://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html) about ViewPager.

Comment: I edited the first post with some code, anyway my main doubt (and the key to solve my problem, maybe) is the "netIstance()"...I tried to add it to getItem(...) function of my class PagerAdapter but it is unknow

Comment: in your PagerAdapter: change _private List<Fragment> fragments;_ to private List<Class<? extends Fragment>> fragments; Only then, you would be able to call _newInstance()_ when in getItem(..). Have a careful look in my code snippet.

Comment: I changed it as you suggested, but changing List in ArrayList... = new ArrayList...() because of NullPointException. Anyway, the problem persists, when I swipe next or previous fragment are the old one not the new instance

Comment: I mean the swiping to the next or to the previous Fragment it is the old one and not a new instance. Sorry for grammatical mistake

Comment: OK, I re-factored the code example to be more complete. This should work now. I tested it myself :)

Comment: Ok, now the Fragment is costantly up-to-date! but there's another issue: overriding FragmentStatePagerAdapter.getItemPosition that returns POSITION_NONE, the Fragment titleIndicator doesn't mark the correct title and it marks a blank space! To mark the correct title I have to move a bit the Fragment to right or left